# Bypass log .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to bypass this login because i don't have the rest of the source /core
*sorry in advanced because i am a newbie i only know python and php :3

````
var  lgnusr = $('#lgnusr'),lgnpss = $('#lgnpss');
$(document).ready(function(){
    //---------------------------------------
    $('.inpx input').on('focus',function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('animat');
    }).on('blur',function(){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('animat');
        if($('.denger').hasClass('hide') === false){$('.denger').addClass('hide');}
    }) ;
    $('#signbtn').on('click',function(){
    if(isempty(lgnusr)){lgnusr.parent().addClass('error');}else if(isempty(lgnpss)){lgnpss.parent().addClass('error');}else{
        var obj = {user:lgnusr.val().trim(),pass:lgnpss.val().trim(),csrf:$(this).data('csrf'),rem:$('#remmber').prop('checked')};
        $('.loading').removeClass('hide');
        $.post("./core/",{qlogin:JSON.stringify(obj)},
            function (data) {
                $('.loading').addClass('hide');
                if(data.ok === true){window.location.href = './dashboard'}else{$('.denger').removeClass('hide');}
            },
            "json"
        ).fail(function(){alert('Invalid Request!! Please Refresh The Page and Try Again..');});
    }
    });
    //--------------------------------------

 });```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you replace the fail action:

```
  fail(function(){alert('Invalid Request!! Please Refresh The Page and Try Again..');});
```

by

```
fail(function(){ window.location.href = './dashboard';});
```

you type any password and any user